# not nowhere dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A\subset X$. $int(\bar{A})\neq\phi$ iff $A$ is dense in some open subset of $X$.

Using this I am unable to produce an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric for which $A=\{8\}\bigcup(0,1)$ is sitting inside as a dense subset of this open set. Can anyone please help me to get out of this block or rectify my understanding?.

Answer (score 2):

What the statement says is: $int (\overset - {A})$ is non-emty if and only if there exists a non-empty open set $U$ in $X$ such that $A \cap U$ is dense in $U$. In your example you can take $U=(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. But is there anything incorrect in the following?. $int(\bar{A})=\phi$ iff $\bar{A}^c$ is dense iff $\forall u$, non-empty open, $\exists u\cap\bar{A}^c\neq\phi$ iff $u\cap int(A^c)\neq\phi$ iff $\exists v\subset u$ open non empty such that $v\cap A=\phi$. If I now negate the statement am I not getting back the statement i made in the question?.

Comment: All your equivalences are correct. But when you interpret the last statement you are mistakenly thinking that you have to produce an open set that contains $A$. For the closure of $A$ to have non-empty interior you only need a non-empty open set $U$ (not necessarily containing $A$) such that the part of $A$ in $U$ is dense in $U$.

Comment: I see. This is clear now. thanks!