# Nowhere dense iff not dense in any nonempty open subset

Tags: general-topology

I use the following definitions:

> The set $A\subset X$ is said to be dense in $X$ if $\bar A=X$.
>
> The set $A\subset X$ is said to be nowhere dense in $X$ if $(\bar A)^\circ=\emptyset$.

Yesterday I read a post saying that a set $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$ if and only if $A$ is not dense in any nonempty open subset of $X$.

If $A$ is nowhere dense, by the definition I follow, $(\bar A)^\circ=\emptyset$. It implies that $\bar A$ is not a nonempty open set. That is, $\bar A≠G$ where $G≠\emptyset$ is open. So $A$ is not dense in any nonempty open subset of $X$. I'm confused about the converse part :

Take $A=[0,1]$. Then $(\bar A)^\circ=(0,1)≠\emptyset$. So $A$ isn't nowhere dense. Then $A$ (according to the post) must be dense in some nonempty open subset of $X$. What is that set? $\bar A$ is not an open set. How can the statement be true?

Comment: No, nowhere dense implies that $\bar A$ does not *contain* a non-empty open set.

Comment: For $A,B \subseteq X$, $A$ is said to be dense in $B$ if $\bar A \supseteq B$. So your set is dense in $(0,1)$

Comment: @pks I see. So $A$ need not be a subset of $B$ in order to be dense in $B$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884622/not-nowhere-dense-set/2884629#2884629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your confusion for the converse part, $A$ is dense in the non-empty open set $G = (0,1)$. This is because by the definition of denseness, $A$ is dense in $G$ iff $A \cap G$ is dense in $G$. That is, iff $G \cap (\overline{A \cap G}) = G$. Here, $A \cap G = G$, and $\overline{A \cap G} = A$, so $G \cap (\overline{A \cap G}) = G$.

---

Additionally, the proof you have given for the forward implication is slightly incorrect. You say that $(\bar{A})^0 = \emptyset \implies \bar{A}$ is not a nonempty open set. But this is assuming too much; the correct implication is: $(\bar{A})^0 = \emptyset \implies \bar{A}$ does not *contain* any nonempty open set.

To correct the proof, one could work as follows. Let $(\bar{A})^0 = \emptyset$. Then, $\bar{A}$ does not contain any nonempty open subset of $X$. Let $G$ be a nonempty open subset of $X$. If $A$ is dense in $G$, then $$
G \cap (\overline{A \cap G}) = G.
$$
But,
$$
A \cap G \subset A \implies \overline{A \cap G} \subset \bar{A}.
$$
Therefore, $G \cap (\overline{A \cap G}) \subset G \cap \bar{A} \subset G$. Hence,
$$
G \cap (\overline{A \cap G}) = G \implies G \cap \bar{A} = G \implies G \subset \bar{A}.
$$ 
But this contradicts that $\bar{A}$ does not contain any nonempty open subset of $X$. Hence, $A$ is not dense in $G$.

---

**Further comments:** Your proof breaks down at the point where you conclude from $\bar{A}$ not being a (nonempty) open set to the fact that $A$ is not dense in any nonempty open subset of $X$. In general this is not true.

To see why, we can take the same sets you considered for the reverse implication. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = [0,1]$. Then $\bar{A} = A$, which is not a nonempty open set. But $A$ is still dense in the set $G = (0,1)$. So, just having that $\bar{A}$ is not a nonempty open set does not imply that $A$ is not dense in any nonempty subset of $X$.

Comment: But why _incorrect_? Indeed if the interior is empty it cannot be a nonempty open set, as the interior of an open set is the set itself.

Comment: @HritRoy How did you conclude that if $\bar{A}$ is not a nonempty open subset of $X$, then $A$ is not dense in any nonempty open subset of $X$? You have already shown this is not true in general by your example: take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = [0,1]$. Then $\bar{A} = A$ is not a nonempty open subset of $X$. However, $A$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I did only one part. The other part I didn't even try. So when you're saying my proof is incorrect you mean the one I did was incorrect. But you're talking about the converse part. I don't understand.

Comment: @HritRoy my apologies for all the confusion, I've updated the answer. I should really read the question properly before rushing to answer... I assumed you were trying to prove that $A$ nowhere dense in $X \implies A$ *nowhere dense* in any nonempty open subset of $X$. I didn't see you meant to prove that $A$ is *not dense* in any nonempty open subset of $X$.

Comment: @HritRoy revised the answer...